# How to connect to MySQL database once over multiple classes

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have this program that consists of many classes and half of them work with MySQL database. Right now, I tediously connect to MySQL for each class. I know this is a bad habit to do and I know it's a big mess, which is why I'm wondering if there's a way to connect once and for all at one class. I'm not sure how this connection can be passed on to classes, though. Is it similar to using parameters, or completely different?

Here are some of my classes if anyone wants a reference:

```
import ~~~

public class LoginVerify {
            
    public LoginVerify() {
        
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/grades";
        String username = "root";
        String password = "root";
        
        JPasswordField jpf = new JPasswordField(10);
        JLabel jl = new JLabel("Password: ");
        jl.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        
        JTextField username1 = new JTextField(10);
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Username: ");
        label.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        
        final JButton okay = new JButton("Ok");
        okay.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        okay.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        
        final JButton cancel = new JButton("Cancel");
        cancel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        cancel.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        
        Object[] message = {
                label, username1,
                jl, jpf,
        };
        
        int value = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(
             null,
             message,
             "LOGIN",
             JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, 
             JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, 
             null, 
             new Object[]{okay, cancel}, 
             okay);
        if (value == 0) {
           String user = username1.getText();
           char[] p = jpf.getPassword();
           String pswrd = String.valueOf(p);
           System.out.println("user: " + user);
           System.out.println("password: " + pswrd);

// CONNECTION STARTS HERE
               
               try {    
                   Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
                   System.out.println("connection success!!");
                
                   String sql = "SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE user_id = ? && user_password = ?";
                   PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
                   statement.setString(1, user);
                   statement.setString(2, pswrd);
                   
               ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
               while(rs.next()){
                   String name = rs.getString("user_name");
                   System.out.println(name);
                   new UserMain(user, name, password, null);
               }
            
               ResultSet rows = statement.executeQuery();
               if (!rows.next() ) {
                   JLabel l = new JLabel("Username or password incorrect, please try again.");
                   l.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 15));
                   l.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, l, "ERROR", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                   new LoginVerify();
                }  
               
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("& i oop");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }      
        } else if (value == 1) {
            JOptionPane.getRootFrame().dispose();   
        } else System.exit(0);
        
        return; 
    }
}
```

Comment: *...Is it similar to using parameters,* - yes, that is how you pass objects from one class to another or from one method to another. Why are you using a `while (rs.next)`. Your query should only return a single user/password so you should be using a "if statement".

Comment: @camickr Sorry if this sounds like a lack of knowledge, but - how would you pass around a connection? like `int addNumbers (Connection con)`? Does that do the work? And how would you handle the try and catch exceptions?

Comment: Or you can make the Connection a static variable in your main class and add a static method to you main class to access the connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking for is actually quite complicated. As a general rule, you do **not** want the tight binding between otherwise unrelated bits of code, so on its face, 'reuse the connection' is a horrible idea.

Unfortunately, DB connections are quite heavy, and you also don't want to create a ton of them a second either.

The solution is therefore a convoluted mess. Ordinarily, 'convoluted mess' should first make you go: Really? This problem hasn't been solved? But, this is one of those cases where it mostly hasn't. There are good workarounds though.

### Connection Poolers

What you're looking for is something called a DB connection pool library.

These libraries give you an API access point that gets you a connection. When you're done, you don't close it, you hand it back (sometimes done via closing it - but then the library you are using will give you a proxy connection, and calling close() on the proxy doesn't really close it, it just marks it as available for the next caller).

The reason it's really complicated is that you can do all sorts of stateful things to connections (for example, using mysql's `SET` command, you can change a ton of weird things that lasts for the entire connection), and connections are usually destroyed after a while by the DB engine, so just giving code a connection from a pool is not good enough - you need to 'test' if it still 'works' first, and run a horde of SET statements or otherwise undo any damage that code that previously used that connection caused.

That, and, you'd want a limiter: If there are already, say, 10 connections to the same DB still in progress, a call to 'get a connection' should just block and wait for one of the 10 already in progress connections to get handed back into the pool.

That's **vastly** too many aspects to just knock out as a newbie in a day.

Thus, get a nice, pre-written, open source library that does all this. Or, accept that you just make a connection, every time, let the database engine worry about it. You can of course take the code that makes a new connection and stick it in a static method someplace, and just call that. Now you at least have only one place to edit the JDBC URL and the like.

The go-to connection pooler out there is [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP).

### Your code has some warts

- Do not ever handle exceptions by 'print stack trace and keep going'. By definition you have no idea what happened (clearly the case - your catch block doesn't do anything to deal with the problem), and yet you continue with the code as if nothing happened? This explodes the complexity of your code and means if one thing goes wrong, you get 85 exceptions scrolling along, all but one of them completely irrelevant.

The right 'I dunno and I do not care' catch block is: `throw new RuntimeException("Uncaught", e);`. Update your IDE. Better yet, just throw SQLException onwards. e.g. `psv main()` can (and should!) be declared with `throws Exception`. Better app, less code. win-win.

- You aren't applying try-with-resources. Resources (objects that represent an actual resource that is finite in ways other than just how much RAM your machine has, such as a file handle, a network socket, or, yes, a database connection) **MUST BE CLOSED**. Code can exit for many reasons - you can `return`, or you can throw exceptions. try-with-resources is the solution. You should never make a ResultSet, (Prepared)Statement, or Connection, ever, unless you do it like this:

```
try (ResultSet rs = ....) {
}
```

The try thing means: If code exits the `{}`, in any way (return/break/continue, just run to the end of it, or exceptions), call close on `rs` first.

Failure to do this means those connections just hang around and pretty soon the DB engine just falls over and dies.

- You are storing passwords plaintext in a database. If you do that as a medium sized company, you get a fine of a few million dollars. I assume you're not a company here, but you might want to at the very least comment that this should never make it past 'for personal use / just to learn' stage. Use mysql's own user management (so, have that password be the password of the connection itself), or, use password-specific hashing schemes such as bcrypt. You can search the web for 'java bcrypt' for more.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This is definitely gonna take me some time to read and digest everything, but thanks! As for your last point - yes, I am aware that I should NOT be storing passwords as plain text. However, I have only been coding for a little over a month (student here, warming up for my intense first year uni courses), so what I know and can do right now is limited. I definitely plan on finding a way to secure these passwords but right now it's a to-learn stage.

Comment: Thanks again - I will try to fix the holes in my program as you indicated :)

Answer (score 0):

Connections are expensive and there are tools out there that help with maintaining a set of connections and pooling between them, repurposing a set of open connections instead of creating a new one each time.

If you don't want or can't use one of these tools, at least you might consider creating one connection and using that same connection throughout the life of the process.

I prefer to let an ORM like Hibernate handle this but you could use a DataSource and implement it your self.

Check this link for how to do the later:
https://www.baeldung.com/java-connection-pooling